# Skimage.color took too long for execution

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

i am try to apply specific color over a person in an image. The code function what is given below is working well but it too long for `color.rgb2lab` as well as `color.lab2rgb` to execute. Can any one suggest alternate method for this same application.

```
def apply_color(chosen_color, image, height, width):
    b, g, r = chosen_color[0], chosen_color[1], chosen_color[2]
    val = color.rgb2lab((image / 255.)).reshape(width * height, 3)

    L, A, B = mean(val[:, 0]), mean(val[:, 1]), mean(val[:, 2])
    L1, A1, B1 = color.rgb2lab(np.array((r / 255., g / 255., b / 255.)).reshape(1, 1, 3)).reshape(3, )
    ll, aa, bb = (L1 - L) * intensity, (A1 - A) * intensity, (B1 - B) * intensity
    val[:, 0] = np.clip(val[:, 0] + ll, 0, 100)
    val[:, 1] = np.clip(val[:, 1] + aa, -127, 128)
    val[:, 2] = np.clip(val[:, 2] + bb, -127, 128)
    blush_image = color.lab2rgb(val.reshape(height, width, 3)) * 255
    return blush_image
```

I tried with opencv instead of skimage but it gives an error.

```
val = cv2.cvtColor(image/255, cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB).reshape(width * height, 3)
```

the above oneline code represent the change I try to made instead of 3rd line in above method.
the error what i got,

```
    cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.simd_helpers.hpp:94: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::impl::{anonymous}::CvtHelper<VScn, VDcn, VDepth, sizePolicy>::CvtHelper(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int) [with VScn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<3, 4>; VDcn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<3>; VDepth = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<0, 5>; cv::impl::{anonymous}::SizePolicy sizePolicy = cv::impl::<unnamed>::NONE; cv::InputArray = const cv::_InputArray&; cv::OutputArray = const cv::_OutputArray&]'
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 6 (CV_64F)
```

I hope i explained the problem well enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "the result is not as i expected": what do you mean ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust It gives error what i mean. I had made the changes in the question. Hope it give a proper idea. Thanks.

Comment: By performing this operation `image/255` you are producing a `float` array. `BGR` images can't have a `float` type, they must be 8-bit unsigned integer per channel.  You need a proper conversion back to `uint8` before color conversion, like this: `image = (image/255.).astype(np.uint8)` then apply the `cvtColor` function.

Comment: @stateMachine Thanks for the suggestion but the pixels that generated with `cv2.RGB2LAB` is not same as `color.rgb2lab`. Any alternate suggestion which replicate the 3rd line of method?

Comment: You are not posting your full code, so I can only speculate. Be aware, however, that OpenCV's `imread` loads a `RGB` image as `BGR`. Mind the channel order. Also, check out the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html) to see the conversion formula used by OpenCV. you might not even need the division by `255`.

Comment: Yeah got it. Thank you so much for your time. I got a proper idea @stateMachine